# Correctly unwrapping arctangent function in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to figure out a better way to unwrap the output of *numpy's arctan function*. Lets say I have:

```
import numpy as np
pi = np.pi

angles = np.deg2rad(range(0,5*360))
tangent = np.tan(angles)
arctangent = np.arctan(tangent)
```

Now I have the angles returned by they are only from `-pi/2` to `pi/2`, but I want them back unwrapped (from `0` to `10 pi`). Using the *numpy function* `np.unwrap` does not work for this and I'm not sure why, so I've been using my own function:

```
def arctan_unwrap(phase_data):
    phase = [2 *(x + pi/2) for x in phase_data]
    phase = np.unwrap(phase)
    phase = [(x/2.0 - np.pi/2) for x in phase]
    return phase
```

Which does return the original angles. I'm trying to figure out a way to clean this up or have np.unwrap do this on its own but can't figure it out. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: FYI: `range(0,10*pi)` raises an exception: `TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got float.`

Answer (score 0):

Since `np.tan` and `np.arctan` both return an array, even if the input is a list, your `unwrap` can be written as:

```
np.unwrap(2*(x+np.pi/2))/2-np.pi/2
```

For the test values

```
np.unwrap(2*x)/2
```

works.  But presumably you know what you are doing in adding the `pi/2`.

`np.unwrap` is pure numpy Python, so you can easily study its method.